# Extract data frame (text) from XML, but file has duplicated node names in R

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, xml-parsing

I have an XML file that I am working with and was trying to get output to look like when you use `xmlToDataFrame()`
function in R. However, my file is too complex so this function does not work for me and gives me errors because node names are duplicated and not unique. I am attaching a simplified version of my XML file just to give an understanding of what I want to achieve

```
<HelloWorld created="2022-03-22" id="12we">
  <myname>omi</myname>
</HelloWorld>
<HelloWorld created="2022-03-12" id="18we">
  <myh>59</myh>
  <myfname>Tom</myfname>
  <mylname>John</mylname>
</HelloWorld>
<HelloWorld created="2022-03-30" id="188yye">
  <myh>60</myh>
  <favcolor>grey</favcolor>
  <myfname>Alex</myfname>
  <mylname>Tom</mylname>
</HelloWorld>
```

From this I want the following output to be generated

| id | myname | myh | myfname | mylname | favcolor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12we | Omi | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 18we | NA | 59 | Tom | John | NA |
| 188yye | NA | 60 | Alex | Tom | Grey |

I am new to XML and have tried various things but still no luck in extracting the data correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```r
# library(xml2)
xml <- xml2::read_html("quux.xml") |> xml2::as_list()

## either data.table or dplyr ...
out <- dplyr::bind_rows(xml$html$body)
out <- data.table::rbindlist(xml$html$body, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)

out
# # A tibble: 3 × 5
#   myname    myh       myfname   mylname   favcolor 
#   <list>    <list>    <list>    <list>    <list>   
# 1 <chr [1]> <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>   
# 2 <NULL>    <chr [1]> <chr [1]> <chr [1]> <NULL>   
# 3 <NULL>    <chr [1]> <chr [1]> <chr [1]> <chr [1]>
```

All columns are list-columns due to how the xml was structured. Since we're comfortable that all elements are either length 0 or 1, we can iterate over all of it to extract the first:

```r
out[] <- lapply(out, function(z) sapply(z, function(y) if (is.null(y)) NA else unlist(y)[1]))
out
# # A tibble: 3 × 5
#   myname myh   myfname mylname favcolor
#   <chr>  <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   
# 1 omi    NA    NA      NA      NA      
# 2 NA     59    Tom     John    NA      
# 3 NA     60    Alex    Tom     grey
```

---

Data: file `quux.xml` with contents:

```
<HelloWorld created="2022-03-22" id="12we">
  <myname>omi</myname>
</HelloWorld>
<HelloWorld created="2022-03-12" id="18we">
  <myh>59</myh>
  <myfname>Tom</myfname>
  <mylname>John</mylname>
</HelloWorld>
<HelloWorld created="2022-03-30" id="188yye">
  <myh>60</myh>
  <favcolor>grey</favcolor>
  <myfname>Alex</myfname>
  <mylname>Tom</mylname>
</HelloWorld>
```

Comment: When I run the bind_rows or rbindlist, it works with the simplified dataset but on my actual dataset, I get output of with 0 rows. Do you know what could be causing this

Comment: No I don't, you'll need to update your sample data to reproduce your 0-output condition. Perhaps the issue is _after_ the `read_xml`/`as_list`. Using my code as a template, perhaps if it isn't too large you can provide the output from `dput(xml)`.

Comment: I think the problem is that in the actual data, we have elements of varying lengths not just length 0 or 1. I am getting the following error "Column 1 of item 1 is length 7 inconsistent with column 7 which is length 27. Only length-1 columns are recycled"

Comment: That's a common problem with transforming variable-format XML into a rigidly-structured `data.frame`. Unfortunately there is no single function to do what you want. When I looked at this sample data, I used `str(xml)` to look at the components, and that's how I found that `xml$html$body` works as a starting-point. If your nested data has arbitrary lengths (not just 0/1 as you said), then perhaps look at `out` after `bind_rows`, without `lapply`, and see what things look like. Again, no single solution, it's a process, and it is too sensitive to the XML structure to generalize.